# Onclick function fires Twice with one click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a `foreach`in the razor :

```
<ul>
    @foreach (var node in Model)
    {
        var par = node.Id;
        <li onclick="GetSubMenu(this)" id="@node.Id">
            @node.Title
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

in onclick i called method in the :

```
function GetSubMenu(e) {
    debugger;
    $.ajax({
        type: "Get",
        url: "/Menu/GetSubMenu",
        data: { parentId: e.id },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",

    }).done(function (result) {
        $.each(result, function (index, val) {               
            $("#" + val.ParentId).append("<ul><li onclick='GetSubMenu(this)' id='" + val.Id + "'>" + val.Title + "</li></ul>");

        });
    });
}
```

and in controller i return the submenu of parent menu(which i click on it):

```
   public JsonResult GetSubMenu(string parentId)
    {
        int id = int.Parse(parentId);
        return Json(db.PrmMenus.Where(x => x.ParentId == id), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

the first time all thing was ok, and the sub menu will show properly, but in seccond time when i click on submenu, the onclick function call for submenu and the parent menu again, what is the problem?

Comment: You need to stop the propagation of the `click` event. You can do that by calling the `stopPropagation()` function on that event. Ex: `function GetSubMenu(event, e){... event.stopPropagation();}`, `.... onclick="GetSubMenu(event, this)" .....`

Comment: Are you saying it requests the submenu again when it already has it loaded? Have you tried unbinding the click event from the parent menu once triggered? An alternative would be to add a check to the parent menu to see if the child menu loaded already.

Comment: @jedifans i mean that when the `onclick` fire for sum menus, its fire for all of the it's parent too, how can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, when you click on the child element, It is calling the `onclick` event for the child element and parent element because child is contained inside the  parent!

You can use jQuery `stopPropogation` method to stop bubbling the event. this method prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

Converting your code to unobtrusive javascript

```
<li class="menuItem" id="@node.Id">
     @node.Title
</li>
```

and listen to the `click` event on the items with "menuItem" class

```
$(function(){

   $(document).on("click",".menuItem",function(e){
       e.stopPropagation();

       var id=$(this).attr("id");
       ///Do your ajax call here
   });

});
```

Make sure you build the same sort of markup for child elements in your ajax method's `done` event (one with the same css class)

[Here is a working jsfiddle](http://jsbin.com/cefowirefo/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: I do it as u said, but in this time the onclick function just called for parent node, and when i click on child node the function again called for its parent!!

Comment: Noway! It should work fine. See the working js fiddle here http://jsbin.com/cefowirefo/edit?html,js,output